# Yii - creating a record for a related model and populating the parent form

Tags: forms, yii

this is my first stack overflow question, so I'm keeping my fingers crossed!

Scenario:

I have a relationship between contracts and customers, expressed in the model as:

```
      'customer' => array(self::BELONGS_TO, 'Customer', 'customer_id'),
```

Now, this is fine - I can access my related model in the view without a problem.

What I want, however, is:

- to add the ability to add a 'New Customer' button from within the Create Contract page (which is fine)
- have it fire up the /views/customer/create form (which is also fine)
- but then, once it's created, have it capture the new ID, close the window and return to the Create Contract page with the newly-created Customer ID pre-populated.  I cannot for the life of me work out how to do this :(

Any help appreciated.

Gary

Comment: You can use ajax call to create new customer and use response data to populate contract form...

Answer (score 0):

One way is this that when your actionSave() saves the customer you can redirect the page to something like

> www.website.com/contract/create/CUSTOMER_ID

Now this way you can pass the user ID to the form and have it pre-populated.
With your contract create action being like : -

```
public function actionCreate($user_id = NULL){
    ...
    $model = new Contract();
    if($user_id)
        //You can also check here if the user ID is valid or not
        $model->user_id = $user_id;
    $this->render('create', array(
        'model' => $model
    ));
}
```

Another way is that you can put the user ID in session and redirect the user to Contract Create page and fetch the user ID there and again pass it to the model as above.

Hope it helps with the issue.

Comment: Thanks for this - and it totally makes sense, but in terms of the flow of pages...how would I do this if I wanted to begin on the Contract page, then fire up the New Customer page, and then capture that ID on my original page?

Does that make sense? I can see this working if I began with the customer and then got redirected to the contract - but what I was hoping for was to be able to fill in the contract info, get to the customer bit, think 'oh no I need to create a new one of those', and be able to go off, create one, then have the data come back to the contract form I was working on...

Comment: You have 1-1 relationship between customer and contract, right?